# Open Source Spring and Hibernate application with a detailed documentation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Though I have found many spring and hibernate application open source on Sourceforge.net and code.google.com, none has really a thorough documentation. Can anyone please give a pointer to and open source project with a detailed documentation.

Comment: What about [petclinic](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html)?

Comment: +1 for PetClinic.  Pretty much the standard recipe for a basic spring-hibernate webapp.